# Accessing PHPMyAdmin via URL (without cPanel)

Tags: web-hosting, mysql, cpanel, database, phpmyadmin

I am having issues accessing PHPMyAdmin from cPanel. It will not allow me to as I am logged in a root.

I cannot seem to be able to make another account for cPanel either, and research indicates this is not possible.

I thought I could just login directly to a PHPMyAdmin database using a database username and password and URL extension or port number but I cannot find any information on how.

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Download phpmyadmin, upload to your site. Done.

Comment: Can you close this as solved?

Comment: @Prasad cant till X amount of time has passed

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Or, even better, [Adminer](http://adminer.org), which is only one file so it is much easier to upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue was the user for that cPanel account actually had an identical password to my WHM account and this threw an error (though user names were different). I changed it and it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the phpmyadmin through the administration privileges. Just click on the icon of phpmyadmin and run it as an administrator. No need to go to the control panel. Hope this will reduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Download PHPMyAdmin install it using your user name and password. The documentation explains how: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html .

However, you need to be careful at setting up your phpmyadmin.  Don't let other people know that it exists.  You need to understand the risk of installing MySQL management software over the public accessible folder.

If security and feature is not a concern, you may want to try adminer, it provides a  lighter and faster interface. For reference, you may also want to try DBNinja or SqlBuddy.